Count all the elements of a set of integers $\{1,\dots,31\}$ that are $6\ \mathrm{mod}\ 7$.
I'd like to find an equation to count all numbers from a set of integers from $1$ to $31$ that satisfies the equation $x\ \mathrm{mod}\ 7 = 6$.
It's a problem related to days of the month and weeks. Considering that day $1$ is monday, then all such $x$s are saturdays. How many saturdays are there?
Consider this set of an arithmetic progression, where $a_1=1$, $a_n=31$ and $d=1$
$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31\}$$
Now consider this subset where all elements are $6\ \mathrm{mod}\ 7$, $\{6, 13, 20, 27\}$ (total: $4$ elements)
What equation could I use to count the elements of this subset ($6\ \mathrm{mod}\ 7)$, giving only $a_1=1$, $a_n=31$ and $d=1$ of the original set?

Welcome to MSE.  Here is a Mathjax tutorial.  How about $\left\lfloor\dfrac{A_n-A_1}{7d}\right\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function?

Experiment using different Arithmetic Progressions(AP), You will observe that the elements which leave the same remainder when divided by a number "p" , will form a new AP with common difference $ \frac{p}{gcd(p,d)} $ where "d" is the common difference of the given AP

7n+6, n from 0 to 3
